# Is there a DRY way to convert values prior to the transformation?

Tags: xslt

Lets say I have the following xml.

```
<root>
  <data>
    <a>ATTITUDE_ANNOYED</a>
    <b>ATTITUDE_CAUTIOUS</b>
    <c>25</c>
    <d>30</d>
  </data>
</root>
```

Ignoring the schema of my output, I want my output to present A as "Cautious" (one level up from annoyed), B as "
Pleased" (one level up from Cautious") and I want to perform some maths on C and D to convert the value into something slightly different.

I've had a look at a bunch of similar questions here (and I'm new to XSLT so maybe I don't quite get it) but a lot of the solutions appear to be "in-line", i.e. you modify the result as you transform it. This is okay but in my real example there are a lot of these values and I don't want to be performing the exact same conversion in multiple places (DRY). I just want to more or less pre-process the entire document and convert a bunch of values into other values (using just a few formulas) before I start the transformation.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I'm not particularly interested in performance so is there a way that I can run a prior transformation to easily transform specific values without modifying the structure?

UPDATE: (DevNull asked for my output desires) The output isn't exactly finalised. I'm trying to help a group at CivFanatics produce a guide on the differences between the AIs whose values derive from an xml file. There are a ton of leaders and a ton of values that need converting, by hand its taking them 2 hours per leader at the moment and the final formatting hasn't been decided on so I thought we'd all save time by using something like XLST.

Here is a rough example of a demo I'm working on.

```
<xsl:template match="data"> 
  <h3>Attitude Thresholds</h3>
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>Will open borders</td><td><xsl:value-of select="a"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Will trade techs</td><td><xsl:value-of select="b"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

To clarify A and B are OpenBordersRefuseAttitudeThreshold and TechRefuseAttitudeThreshold. The guide is more readable if these are WillOpenBordersAt and WillTradeTechAt as opposed to the original values in the xml file so I need to nudge them up a value for the final output.

There are additional conversions that have been discussed:

```
iWonderConstructRand -> Builds Wonders

0 -> 0/10
5 -> 1/10
10 -> 2/10
15 -> 3/10
20 -> 4/10
25 -> 5/10
30 -> 6/10
35 -> 7/10
40 -> 8/10
45 -> 9/10
50 -> 10/10
```

So that's values such as C or D. They range between 0-50 and should be put into a 0-10 format for readability. There are a fair few of these values too.

Also there are conversions like "GoodieBaddie" which vary from 0 to 10. Which we wish to convert to something like:

```
0-3  -> Bad(x)
4-6  -> Neutral(x)
7-10 -> Good(x)
```

Where (x) is the original value.
Am I even using the right tool for the job here or is it borderline? I figured XLST would be a good choice to enable other contributors to not have to rely on the devs to make changes to the formatting/layout (as xlst is easier to edit then say C# or Python).

Comment: An actual example of your desired XML output would help a lot.

Comment: Really? I thought the question was orthogonal to output.

Comment: I must not understand the question then.

Comment: Well I've added some information about the output along with some context. Does that help describe my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:attitudes>
   <a val="1">ANNOYED</a>
   <a val="2">CAUTIOUS</a>
   <a val="3">PLEASED</a>
 </my:attitudes>

 <xsl:variable name="vAttitudes" select="document('')/*/my:attitudes/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(., 'ATTITUDE_')]/text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vVal" select=
  "$vAttitudes[. = substring-after(current(), '_')]/@val"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="concat('ATTITUDE_', $vAttitudes[@val = $vVal+1])"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[floor(.) = .]/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(round(. div 5), '/10')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <data>
        <a>ATTITUDE_ANNOYED</a>
        <b>ATTITUDE_CAUTIOUS</b>
        <c>25</c>
        <d>30</d>
    </data>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <data>
      <a>ATTITUDE_CAUTIOUS</a>
      <b>ATTITUDE_PLEASED</b>
      <c>5/10</c>
      <d>6/10</d>
   </data>
</root>
```

Comment: wow that's awesome. "*[floor(.) = .]/text()" is hilariously cheeky. My real life file contains way more values so I still need to work through a few problems, however this is a great starting point for me! Thanks.

Comment: @Quibblesome: You are welcome. Yes, XPath is a very powerful selection language -- this coupled with XSLT templating gives us an excellent transformation language -- not to speak about XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0.